# Can't Symmetrize Amatures Correctly

Tags: armature, axis

Whenever I Symmetrize my Armatures they always flip on the wrong axis. I've tried turning the model, and it always ends up flipping the wrong way

[image: Its not flipping the right way]

Comment: I guess it is because your model is too small. select the armature and try scaling it up..

Comment: I tried that, it still doesn't work

Comment: Try putting the origin of the mesh at he center of the mesh, and the origin of the armature in the center of the armature (or on its symmetry axis), if you don't have that already. And then put them both at the center of the scene. Shift+C and Shift+S > Selection to Cursor can help with that.